# How to lengthen scroll when using scrollTop()?

Tags: html, css, scrolltop

I'm currently using a scrollTop() method in my [website](http://tt1.fadn303.net/students/samchang/index.html). It works fine on my screen but I realized that when the homepage is on a bigger screen, the scrollbar will not scroll down. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please show any code. You may change it to scroll down on an anchor point instead of height.

Comment: What's the design reason behind your assignments being invisible until the user scrolls down (i.e. what's the end result you're going for)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`Without editing your scroll function you only need to ensure your body height. It should be at least 50px > your window Height. Inside of your $(document).ready add this:

```
$("body").css("height", window.outerHeight + 50 + "px")
```

IE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        $("body").css("height", window.outerHeight + 50 + "px")
});
```